# Laravel - Create Array from Dot Notation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not able to do get it right. If I have an array notation like this:

```
['email', 'privacy.language', 'privacy.phonenr', 'privacy.user.id']
```

I would like to get an array that looks like this:

```
[
 0 => 'email',
 'privacy' => [
      0 => 'language',
      1 => 'phonenr',
      'user' => [
         0 => 'id'
      ]
 ],
]
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
protected function undotArray(array $fields) 
{
    $array = [];

    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {

        $keys = explode('.', $field);

        if(count($keys) == 1){
            $array[] = $keys[0];
            continue;
        }

        if(count($keys) == 2){
            $array[$keys[0]][] = $keys[1];
            continue;
        }

        if(count($keys) == 3){
            $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][] = $keys[2];
        }

    }


    return $array;

}
```

But as you see the "if conditions" are similar and they repeat themselves, depending on the number of dots. I feel like that I need to use a recursive function here, but I don't know how.

Comment: what you want is probably not correct. Why? because in laravel dot notation is used for keys only, so to set to those keys with `data_set`, and get with `data_get`. What you're trying to do is to switch keys with values at the last moment

Comment: @VladyslavStartsev it's hard to explain why I need this, but I'm trying to add a function to Laravel API Resource. For example when you say `user => new UserResource()` I want to add extra fields that are normally hidden. So I'm calling it like this: `user => (new UserResource())->makeVisible(['email', 'privacy.phonenr'])`. With that I get the result user with the email and when the relationship privacy is loaded I get the phonenr. I hope you understand this. It's quite useful :)